# echo UnityInstallationDir command has just stuck me from 2 days

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
  Error 1   The command "echo UnityInstallationDir 'E:\Editor'
  echo UnityProjectDir 'F:\WINDOWS STORE WORK\Unity Projects\0444-june-2015\Unity First Project_12April-15-8.00pm - Copy'
  echo Copying assemblies...
  copy /Y "C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\Archery Bow Master\ArcheryBowMaster\Unprocessed\*" "C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\ArcheryBowMaster\Archery      Bow Master\"copy /Y "F:\WINDOWS STORE WORK\Unity Projects\0444-june-2015\Unity First Project_12April-15-8.00pm - Copy\bin\Store  8.1\x86\Master\Unprocessed\Assembly-CSharp.dll" "F:\WINDOWS STORE         WORK\Unity Projects\0444-june-2015\Unity First Project_12April-15-8.00pm -               Copy\bin\Store 8.1\x86\Master\Assembly-CSharp.dll"
  copy /Y "F:\WINDOWS STORE WORK\Unity Projects\0444-june-2015\Unity First Project_12April-15-8.00pm - Copy\bin\Store     8.1\x86\Master\Unprocessed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll" "F:\WINDOWS STORE    WORK\Unity Projects\0444-june-2015\Unity First Project_12April-15-8.00pm -    Copy\bin\Store 8.1\x86\Master\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll"
  if exist "F:\WINDOWS STORE WORK\Unity Projects\0444-june-2015\Unity First Project_12April-15-8.00pm - Copy\bin\Store  8.1\x86\Master\Unprocessed\Assembly-CSharp.pdb" copy /Y "F:\WINDOWS STORE  WORK\Unity Projects\0444-june-2015\Unity First Project_12April-15-8.00pm -  Copy\bin\Store 8.1\x86\Master\Unprocessed\Assembly-CSharp.pdb" "F:\WINDOWS       STORE WORK\Unity Projects\0444-june-2015\Unity First Project_12April-15-      8.00pm - Copy\bin\Store 8.1\x86\Master\Assembly-CSharp.pdb"
  if exist "F:\WINDOWS STORE WORK\Unity Projects\0444-june-2015\Unity First Project_12April-15-8.00pm - Copy\bin\Store  8.1\x86\Master\Unprocessed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.pdb" copy /"F:\WINDOWS STORE WORK\Unity Projects\0444-june-2015\Unity First Project_12April-15-      8.00pm - Copy\bin\Store 8.1\x86\Master\Unprocessed\Assembly-CSharp-      firstpass.pdb" "F:\WINDOWS STORE WORK\Unity Projects\0444-june-2015\Unity       First Project_12April-15-8.00pm - Copy\bin\Store 8.1\x86\Master\Assembly-      CSharp-firstpass.pdb"
     echo Running AssemblyConverter...
     "E:\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\metrosupport\Tools\AssemblyConverter.exe" -      platform=wsa81 "F:\WINDOWS STORE WORK\Unity Projects\0444-june-2015\Unity       First Project_12April-15-8.00pm - Copy\bin\Store 8.1\x86\Master\Assembly-CSharp.dll" "F:\WINDOWS STORE WORK\Unity Projects\0444-june-2015\Unity   First Project_12April-15-8.00pm - Copy\bin\Store 8.1\x86\Master\Assembly- CSharp-firstpass.dll" "C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\Archery Bow Master\Archery  Bow Master\\Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll" "C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\Archery Bow Master\Archery Bow Master\\Assembly-UnityScript.dll" "C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\Archery Bow Master\Archery Bow Master\\Boo.Lang.dll" "C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\Archery Bow Master\Archery Bow Master\\PlayMaker.dll" "C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\Archery Bow Master\Archery Bow Master\\UnityEngine.dll" "C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\Archery Bow Master\Archery Bow Master\\UnityEngine.UI.dll" "C:\Users\Faisal\Desktop\Archery Bow Master\Archery Bow Master\\WinRTLegacy.dll"
 echo AssemblyConverter done.
" exited with code 1.   Archery Bow Master
```

Comment: you might get more details about your error using recommendations posted [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/comments/776253/view.html).

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn from it for your next question....

Answer (score 0):

Fix the paths in "**UnityCommon.props**" ( Visual Studio solution's folder) ;)

Comment: i failed that folder path,,can u show screen shot??where exactly i have to go to solve .....to fix that path...

Comment: In your project's root folder (F:\WINDOWS STORE    WORK\Unity Projects\0444-june-2015\) 
this file http://clip2net.com/s/3p81cUP

Comment: I have Tried but found just "UnityCommon" in my project not showing "UnityCommon.props" and that file "UnityCommon" not opening in which format i have to open....just confused from where i can solve issue......

Comment: it is text document - notepad, notepad++ etc. you cant see the extension because in your explorer options known extensions are hidden

Comment: Make a screenshot of your project folder